# Finding the unique paths through a Neo4j graph

Tags: neo4j

I have a Neo4j graph with 12 inputs and 4 outputs, and am trying to write a query with the Java Traverser that will return the 14 unique paths from an input to an output node.  All the queries I have tried return only a subset of the 14 paths.  For example, the code below returns 4 paths, but the other 10 all stop 1 node short of the output.

```
RelationshipType relType = RelationshipTypes.EDGE;
TraversalDescription td = new TraversalDescriptionImpl()
      .depthFirst()
      .relationships(relType, Direction.OUTGOING);
for (Node node : inputs){
    Traverser tv = td.traverse(node);
    Iterator<Path> iter = tv.iterator();
    // ... print path
}
```

I've tried uniqueness and depth settings as well, with no effect.

The query below returns all 14 paths using the web interface, but when I use the ExecutionEngine class, I only get 13 paths back.

```
START s=node(*) 
MATCH (s)-[p:EDGE*]->(c)
WHERE s.type! = "INPUT" AND c.type! = "OUTPUT"
RETURN p
```

How do I get all the unique paths using the Java API?

Comment: Your data set seems small enough to share, could you post it at [Neo4j Console](http://console.neo4j.org) and share the link? Also, your cypher query may not return paths in the sense that you think, try prepending `path=` to the pattern in your `MATCH` clause and return `path` if you want a path. Your `p` is a collection of relationships.

Comment: Test data is on http://console.neo4j.org/?id=1nom33.

Answer (score 0):

```
START s=node(*) 
WHERE s.type = "INPUT" 
MATCH (s)-[p:EDGE*]->(c) 
WHERE c.type = "OUTPUT" 
RETURN p;
```

This is kinda similar to what you had.  It returns 14 entries based on the Neo4j console example you provided.